# i wanted to store the ascii value of individual strings in a line how can i do that using getbyte function

Tags: java

This is my following code it doesnot work why?
i have been thinking getting ascii values using getbyte function rather adding each of them individually how would i do that.

public class Stringtest {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char ch;
    String  str="";
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter A Line");
    String S=sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){
    ch=S.charAt(i);
        while(ch!=' '){
        str=str+ch;
        }
        byte[] barr=str.getBytes();
    for(int z=0;z<barr.length;z++){
    System.out.println(barr[z]);
    }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: `ch` doesn't change in `while(ch!=' '){ str=str+ch; }` so you end up in infinite loop.

Comment: Anyway you need to learn that indentation is important. It allows us to read code easier and see proper scope. Most editors have tools which indent code for us.

Comment: I think your issue is that your while(ch!=' ') should have been an if(ch!=' ') there is no point looping through a single item ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter A Line");
String S=sc.nextLine();
byte[] barr=S.getBytes(/* "US-ASCII" */); //I believe by default it's this? but not 100% sure about it need to check documentation.
for(int z=0;z<barr.length;z++){
    if(barr[z]!=32){              //Add this - if the char is not ' '
        System.out.println(barr[z]);
    }
}
```

This should serve the same purpose that you were doing -- unless you wanted to apply the usage of charAt() method.

Re-looking at your code, I understand what you are trying to do and would like to tell you why you have the current error (if you do not want to use the above approach and tackle this on your own!). As @Pshemo mentioned, you are stuck in an infinite loop because your while loop continuously checks if that ch is not equal to ' ', without the ch value changing. So for example, if I inputted the line: 'Hello' into your code when I compiled it:

```
//S = "Hello"
for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){
    ch=S.charAt(i);  // ch = 'H'
    while(ch!=' '){ //Checks if ch is NOT EQUAL to ' ' -- returns true
        str=str+ch; // '' = '' + ' '. Now str = ' '
    }
//Now it will loop again because it will check if ch is NOT EQUAL to ' ', which is again true.
//Your str variable will now equal '  '. And the loop again continues infinitely.
```

Edit: So if you want to get the ASCII values of words within a sentence there is a method in the String class called `public String[] split(String regex)`. This method returns a `String[]` and splits the given String by the regex you put.

For example (Taking this from the documentation):

```
String s = "boo:and:foo";
/*Created a variable called stringContainer that will reference String[] (Currently references null)*/
String[] stringContainer; 
/*My variable now references the SERIES of strings that come from splitting the phrase "boo:and:foo"*/
stringContainer = s.split(":");  //Please note that i called the split method using my original string s (which holds "boo:and:foo")
System.out.println(stringContainer[0]); //Prints out "boo"
System.out.println(stringContainer[1]); //Prints out "and"
System.out.println(stringContainer[2]); //prints out "foo"
```

So as you can see you can split a given string into a series of String Objects. Now you may put that in a for loop to obtain their ASCII value via the getBytes method as such:

```
for(String stringInArray : stringContainer){ //For each string in String[]...
    byte[] barr = stringInArray.getBytes("US-ASCII"); //Get the string's byte value and store in barr...
    for(byte b : barr){ //For each byte in byte[]...
        //Note: I used print instead of println here because I don't want it to go to next line yet
        System.out.print(b + ", "); //Print out the byte value + ", "
    }
    //After the whole word's byte value has been printed out, go to new line
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: thanks for you help, but i want to get ascii value of each word using above get byte  rather than ascii value of each character how to do it?

Comment: the what should i do with the statement while(ch!=' ')  because i want to concat a word then find its ascii values .So to concat that character in string i have to add ch in str .First time H will be added or ' ' ?

Comment: Editted my answer to help you with the above problem. The simplified code I posted above did concatenate the words by combining the Strings. I  am assuming you mean to SPLIT the words from the (space)? In that case you would use the ' ' as your delimiter instead of ':' as I put in the above answer.